# Need help in constructing pattern for OR and AND using spacy python

Tags: python, spacy, matcher, phrase

Let's say suppose I have a text saying
input sentence : `Computer programming is the process of writing instructions that get executed by computers. The instructions, also known as code, are written in a programming language which the computer can understand and use to perform a task or solve a problem. Basic computer programming involves the analysis of a problem and development of a logical sequence of instructions to solve it.`

and I have to find if any of the phrases matches the given text sentences.

```
or_phrases = [efficient, design]
expected output - yes, because the above input sentence has a word "efficient"

and_phrase = [love, live]
expected output : None. Because the above input sentence doesn't have love or live anywhere in the entire sentence. Order  of the words doesn't matter. To convert this into a reg expr:
re.match('(?=.*love)|(?=.*live)'

Looking to put this rule into spacy's phrase or token matcher
```

Is there a way to put this grammar pattern into a spacy pattern matcher?

or_phrases should give me sentences having either of the words.

and_phrases should give me sentences having both the words.

Comment: Could you please provide some more example input sentences and say, what exactly should be your output?

Comment: @krisograbek sure Edited my question above.

Answer (score 0):

With spacy you can easily make an `OR` phrase by using `'TEXT': {'IN':["word1", "word2"]}`. In your example this will look like this:

```
text = """Computer programming is the process of writing instructions that get executed by computers. The instructions, also known as code, are written in a programming language which the computer can understand and use to perform a task or solve a problem. Basic computer programming involves the analysis of a problem and development of a logical sequence of instructions to solve it. """

doc = nlp(text)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
or_pattern = [[
        {"TEXT": {"IN": ["process", "random"]}} # the list of "OR" words
]]
matcher.add("or_phrases", or_pattern)

for sent in doc.sents:
    matches = matcher(sent)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        print(sent)
```

I still can't come up with an easy solution for `AND` but I'll try